# DropdownlistFor in a loop, null model on submit

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am having an issue with the values selected in multiple dropdownlistfor(s) being available in the controller when the form is submitted.  The model is always blank.  I know there are issues with mvc having dropdowns in loops but I thought I have solved for this.  Let me know what you think.

**View**

```
@model DataDictionaryConversion.Models.FinalResults

@{ using (Html.BeginForm("SaveMapping", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Converted to Name</th>
                            <th>Your Project Name</th>
                            <th><input type="button" 
onclick="checkAll()"/></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    @{for (int x = 0; x < Model.DDObjects.Count(); x++)
                        {
                            var isSelection = false;
                            <tr>
                                <td class="filterable-cell">@Model.DDObjects[x].ObjectName</td>
                                <td class="filterable-cell">

@Html.DropDownList(Model.DDObjects[x].ObjectName, new 
SelectList(Model.ProjectObjects, "ObjectName", "ObjectName"), 
htmlAttributes: new { @id = "ddlObject", @class = "js-example-basic-single" })</td>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="NoValue- 
   @Model.DDObjects[x].ObjectName" name="NoValue- 
   @Model.DDObjects[x].ObjectName" onclick="byPassObject(this)" /> Object 
Not 
Used
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:right; height:20px"><input 
type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Generate Conversion Mapping" 
/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveMapping([FromServices]ApplicationDbContext context, FinalResults model)
    {


        return View("Mapping");
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class FinalResults
{
public IList<FinalObjectModel> ProjectObjects { get; set; }
public IList<Conversion_CSD_ObjectNameLearningModel> DDObjects { 
get; set; }
```

FinalResults model is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `Html.DropDownList`. The first param there is a string, which should correspond with the name you're binding to. However, you're passing the value of `Model.DDObjects[x].ObjectName`, not literally something like `"DDOjbects[0].ObjectName"`.

Instead, you should be using `Html.DropDownListFor` like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DDObjects[x].ObjectName, ...)
```

Then, the select list will be bound correctly.

Comment: Wow, I even wrote it in the description but didn't notice I didn't type it out correctly.  Guess it just took another set of eyes.  Thanks.